# cannot insert row with Hibernate/JPA entityManager, MySQL and Spring

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I've tried to implement JPA entityManager provided by Hibernate and update my database.

I use MySQL 5.7 server, where username is "tutorial" and password is just "password". I've done some configurations and tried to simply insert a row into the "country" table with columns: id(int)(pk)(auto_inc) and country(varchar), but it don't affect my database.
In country table are already 4 rows: (1, "Poland"), (2,"Slovakia"), (3, "Ukraine") and (4, "Czech Republic").

Controller:

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import pl.hibernate.basics.daos.CustomersDetailsDAO;
import pl.hibernate.basics.model.Country;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    @Autowired
    private CustomersDetailsDAO customersDetailsDAO;


    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home() {

                Country country = new Country();
        country.setCountry("Lithuania");

        logger.info("Country Entity: " + country);

        customersDetailsDAO.insertCountry(country);

        return "home";
    }


}
```

CustomersDetailsDAOImpl:

```
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import pl.hibernate.basics.model.Country;

@Transactional
@Component
public class CustomersDetailsDAOImpl implements CustomersDetailsDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void insertCountry(Country country) {
        em.persist(country);

    }

}
```

Entity Class:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="country")
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String country;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Country [id=" + id + ", country=" + country + "]";
    }


}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd">

    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="username" value="tutorial" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="emFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="pl.hibernate.basics" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"
        class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />

</beans>
```

Console output (Note logger info at the end):

```
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:JPA Hibernate Spring WebMVC Application' did not find a matching property.
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          May 19 2015 14:58:38 UTC
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.23.0
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_60-b27
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\apache-tomcat-8.0.23-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.23
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\apache-tomcat-8.0.23-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.23
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\eclipse\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\apache-tomcat-8.0.23-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.0.23\endorsed
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1250
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_60\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_60/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_60/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_60/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\xampp\php;;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin;C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\eclipse;;.
sty 29, 2016 2:31:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
sty 29, 2016 2:31:28 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
sty 29, 2016 2:31:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
sty 29, 2016 2:31:28 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
sty 29, 2016 2:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1372 ms
sty 29, 2016 2:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
sty 29, 2016 2:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.23
sty 29, 2016 2:31:31 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
sty 29, 2016 2:31:31 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
sty 29, 2016 2:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri Jan 29 14:31:32 CET 2016]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/persistence.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean 'dataSource' of type [class org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#e956be6' of type [class org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
WARN : org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence - HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Bean 'emFactory' of type [class org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6441d7e2: defining beans [homeController,customersDetailsDAOImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,dataSource,emFactory,transactionManager,persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; root of factory hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 6254 ms
sty 29, 2016 2:31:38 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'appServlet'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'appServlet-servlet': startup date [Fri Jan 29 14:31:38 CET 2016]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader - Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@472f3baa: defining beans [mvcContentNegotiationManager,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter,homeController,customersDetailsDAOImpl,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@6441d7e2
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String pl.hibernate.basics.controllers.HomeController.home()
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapped URL path [/resources/**] onto handler 'org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler#0'
INFO : org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - FrameworkServlet 'appServlet': initialization completed in 1362 ms
sty 29, 2016 2:31:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
sty 29, 2016 2:31:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
sty 29, 2016 2:31:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 11657 ms
INFO : pl.hibernate.basics.controllers.HomeController - Country Entity: Country [id=0, country=Lithuania]
```

Comment: First remove the messing around with the `current_session_context_class` property as that breaks proper integration. Next move the insert method to a service and make that transactional (first it is a bad idea to make your web layer the transactional boundary, second internal method calls don't pass through the proxy and aren't transactional by default). Finally your controller is loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` any `<tx:annotation-driven />` in the root context doesn't exist for him (AOP is only applied on the same application context).

Comment: Ok i updated my code, but it still doesn't work. @M.Deinum Could you take a look?

Comment: and how is your dao coming to life? Nothing in the configuration is going to trigger the creation.

Comment: but i registered my dao as a bean through @Component annotation and then injected to a private field in controller and used it. I've just tried to get the Country entity through the dao and it works and inserting to Country doesn't.

Comment: That is nice, but there is no component scan in this configuration. I also commented that when having a `<tx:annotation-driven />` in your root context (aka `ContextLoaderLIstener`) that isn't going to do anything for beans loaded in the servlet context (aka `DispatcherServlet`).

Comment: There is component-scan in root-context.xml so i think that the dao is managed by root-context. Am i wrong?

Comment: Ok i've declared dao as a bean in root-context and now it works. But why earlier it didn't if there was a component-scan in root context? @M.Deinum could you dispel my doubts?

Comment: Because if you have the same component-scan in the dispatcher servlet you get 2 instances of a bean.